# Why are the following Binding expressions not the same?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to set the text of a `TextBox` inside a custom user control. The following works fine:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyCustomControl}"  >
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyCustomControl}">

                <Canvas>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomControlText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyCustomControl}}}">
                </Canvas>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I tried to separate out the `Text` property of `TextBox` explicitly, initially to add a `MultiBinding`. When this didn't work, I noticed that also with a single `Binding` it didn't work. I mean the following:

```
<Canvas>
     <TextBox>
         <TextBox.Text>
             <Binding Path="CustomControlText" Source="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyCustomControl}}"/>
         </TextBox.Text>
     </TextBox>
</Canvas>
```

I thought this should be exactly equivalent to the former case, but this doesn't actually work. Though it compiles fine, this `Binding` never finds any value. Why are the two different, and how can the latter be fixed into a functioning expression?

Comment: Is CustomControlText a dependency property? or is that something that you are binding in the data context ?

Comment: Yes, it is a DependencyProperty.

Comment: dependency property of MyCustomControl? or of the window/page that you are in?

Comment: Sorry, I see I accidentally switched the two in my example, hence the confusion - fixed this now. So `MyCustomControl` owns a `DependencyProperty` called `CustomControlText`.

Comment: How about adding "mode" and "UpdateSourceTrigger" to the binding variable?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added `Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` to the latter example, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: to make sure i got it right ... the textbox is to display a text from a different control?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63415/discussion-between-yellow-and-aggietech).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RelativeSource` instead of `Source` in your Binding.

```
<Binding Path="CustomControlText" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyCustomControl}}"/>
```

Comment: That is a great catch !

Comment: Aaargh, that's a terrible catch! :P But thanks, this is a good thing to know, and indeed solved the problem.